# How can I debug a CSS Paged Media template?

Tags: css-paged-media, antenna-house

I'm working on a CSS Paged Media template, and I'm running into some issues with Paged Media-specific CSS items (e.g. @page): I've got a rule that applies a background-image on the last page of the document, but this background image turns up in other locations in my document.

I use the Antennahouse rendering engine, which allows me to view the rendered result, but doesn't show me why elements are rendered the way they are.

I use the Developer tools in Chrome or Firefox to see which CSS elements are applied to each bit of HTML, but Chrome and Firefox don't understand Paged Media selectors like @page. Are there tools that offer a similar view and that understand paged media? Or other ways I can approach this?

Comment: Can you also make a question for the current problem?

Answer (score 1):

One approach -- in the long tradition of `printf()` statements in code -- is to put/duplicate information into named strings or running elements that are directed to page-margin boxes that you are not otherwise using.